# Vector element outputting garbage

Tags: c++, vector, output, garbage

I got a function in my class that returns a vector holding User and Pass read from an ini file.

Here's the code that reads it. I added outputs here for tests and it's reading it successfully.

```
vector<char*> Main::GetAccount(int i)
{
    vector<char*> LoginInfo;

    char szUser[13];
    char szPass[13];
    char szBuf[3];

    _itoa_s(i, szBuf, 10);

    GetPrivateProfileString(szBuf, "UserID", "User", szUser, 13, ".\\accounts.ini");
    GetPrivateProfileString(szBuf, "Pass", "Pass", szPass, 13, ".\\accounts.ini");

    if (strcmp(szUser, "User") == 0)
    {
        char szBuffer[80];
        sprintf_s(szBuffer, "Cannot read account %i.", i);
        Log(szBuffer);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        LoginInfo.push_back(szUser);
        LoginInfo.push_back(szPass);

        return LoginInfo;
    }
}
```

And here is where I'm calling it, and where it goes wrong.

```
for (int i = 1; i < main->nBots + 1; i++)
{
    vector<char*> LoginInfo = main->GetAccount(i);

    char* szUser = LoginInfo[0];
    char* szPass = LoginInfo[1];

    cout << szUser << endl << szPass << endl;
}
```

Comment: [undefined behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pushing back pointers to `szUser` and `szPass` into your Vector and return it after that. That's bad because `szUser` and `szPass` are local variables that'll get destroyed once you return from the function.

Now

```
vector<char*> LoginInfo = main->GetAccount(i);

char* szUser = LoginInfo[0];
char* szPass = LoginInfo[1];
```

here you access these pointers that are currently pointing to some garbage. This is **undefined behavior**. You should rethink what you want to do and might want to use `std::string` instead of handling `char *`'s.

By making it a `vector<std::string>` you'll get proper copies of the strings inside and don't have to worry about the ugly `char *`'s pointing to some location that went out of scope.